# Como pegar dados JSON

Tags: javascript, front-end

Galera eu fiz uma lista em JSON com o nome de lista_json.js e coloquei ela no *head* do HTML, porém gostaria de pegar ela no *body*, os códigos funcionam no console mas não consigo imprimir na tela, o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="lista_json.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>lista</h1>
        <p id="teste"></p>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="lista_json.js" > 

            document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = pag_1.produto;

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

O ficheiro lista_json.js:

```
var pag_1 = {"produto":"produto1", "valor":1}; 
var pag_2 = {"produto":"produto2", "valor":2}; 
var pag_3 = {"produto":"produto3", "valor":3}; 
var pag_4 = {"produto":"produto4", "valor":4}; 
var pag_5 = {"produto":"produto5", "valor":5}; 
var pag_6 = {"produto":"produto6", "valor":6}; 
var pag_7 = {"produto":"produto7", "valor":7}; 
var pag_8 = {"produto":"produto8", "valor":8};
```

Comment: Tens algum erro na consola?  não aparece nada?

Comment: Não e no console eu pego os dados, imprimo de varias formas. Porem não funciona no html.

Comment: _"Porem não funciona no html"_, podes explicar melhor?

Answer (score 1):

**Use ele fora do `<script src="">`**

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="teste.js" ></script>
<script>
    document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = pag_1.produto;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

seu erro 'e na formatacao da tag `script`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = pag_1.produto;
</script>
```

no html5 nao 'e necessario usar `type="text/javascript"` recomendando para html4-

extra vc pode fazer todo o seu json junto:

```
var pag_1 = [{"produto":"produto1", "valor":1},{"produto":"produto2", "valor":2}];
```

e acessar dessa formar `pag_1[1].produto`

Answer (score -1):

Use a função getJSON do Jquery:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("lista_json.js", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

(Não vai aparecer o nada pq não tem o JSON, exemplo pego do site W3school)